# http-аутификация для 1с

Tags: php

У меня на сайте реализована выгрузка товаров. 1с подключается по заданной мной ссылке, и получает список товаров.

Каким образом можно сделать авторизацию для 1C, чтобы просто так по прямой ссылке нельзя было получить список товаров ?

Правильно ли я понимаю что для этого нужно сделать http-аутификацию ? Как это делать на сайте? И как мне писать инструкцию 1С-никам, чтобы они понимали как авторизоваться?

Comment: OAuth2 - Юююхуууу!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Каким образом можно сделать авторизацию для 1C, чтобы просто так по
>   прямой ссылке нельзя было получить список товаров ?

Делайте авторизацию по токену и пусть 1С через неё стучится по ссылке. Как это сделать подробно расписывать не стану, т.к. тема уже избитая и легко гуглится по запросу "авторизация по токену".

> И как мне писать инструкцию 1С-никам, чтобы они понимали как
>   авторизоваться?

Так и пишите, что должна сделать 1С по шагам чтобы получить данные.

Comment: Согласен со @Streletz!!! :)